# angularjs form with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm having trouble with a form using angularjs/php/mysql to make a quite simple CRUD.
My form pass correctly the text inputs but I can't pass the `<select>` value.

The `ng-option` expression below is wrong but I can't find how to write it.

```
<div ng-controller="formController">
    <form ng-submit="addVinyl()" novalidate class="simple-form">
        Owner: <select ng-model="vinyl.owner" ng-options="user.name for user in users"></select><br />
        Title: <input type="text" ng-model="vinyl.name" /><br />
        Artist: <input type="text" ng-model="vinyl.artist" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Vinyl" />
    </form>
</div>
```

gives this html:

```
<option value="0">hey</option>
<option value="1">hoy</option>
<option value="2">hay</option>
```

My php file gets the good values of the text inputs but doesn't get the '0', '1', '2' or the 'hey', 'hoy', 'hay'... I tried to display `vinyl.owner`and I got `{"NAME":"hey"}` for the first option selected.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-options` is not the same as `ng-repeat`

The correct syntax for your purpose is :

```
ng-options="user.name as user.name for user in users"
```

This is due to the fact that you need a value for the attribute `value`, and that you need a "display text".

find more information inside documentation :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions